# How to add drop-down list instead of a textfield

Tags: swagger-ui

I will put a "Choose Civil Status" parameter inside a POST method in my Swagger-UI, so instead of a text fields I wanted it to be a drop down list, I'm using MVC 3, Can anyone explain how can I do that?

here is my sample code..

```
 [HttpPost]
        public string Generate(string id, Salutation Salutation)
        {
             //code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the controller put

```
var Users = db.TABLENAME;

List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem> ();
list.Add(new ListItem("Please Select", "0"));
foreach (var item in Users)
{
    list.Add(new ListItem(item.ColName , item.UserId.ToString()));
}

ViewBag.UserList = new SelectList(list, "ValueField", "TextField");
```

In View

```
@Html.DropDownList("SomeName", (SelectList)ViewBag.UserList , new { @class = "DropDownList W150 ", value = @ViewBag.SelectedVal })
```

and you will have to declare your ListItem in ModelClasses